# Сравнение двух таблиц по полям, содержащим NULL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблицы `table1` и `table2`.
У каждой из таблиц имеются 3 поля для соотношения записей между таблицами (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`), а так же другие поля.

Я нахожу в `table2` запись по номеру телефона, и хочу вывести соответствующие ей данные из `table1`.

запрос выглядит так:

```
select
  otherfield
from
  table1 c,
  table2 s
where s.phone_number='$phone_number'
  and (s.field1=c.field1 and s.field3=c.field3 and s.field3=c.field3)
limit 1
```

Проблема в том, что поля `field1`,`field2` и `field3` могут быть `NULL`.
Если `table1.field1=NULL` и `table2.field1=NULL`, то при запросе `select` конструкция `s.field1=c.field1` возвращает `false`.

Как этого можно избежать?

Comment: ну добавьте еще `someField IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select otherfield
  from table1 c, table2 s
 where s.phone_number='$phone_number'
   and coalesce(s.field1,'###')=coalesce(c.field1,'###')
   and coalesce(s.field2,'###')=coalesce(c.field2,'###')
   and coalesce(s.field3,'###')=coalesce(c.field3,'###')
 limit 1
```

`coalesce` превращает все NULL в указанное значение, это значение надо указать таким, что бы в базе точно не встретилось.

К сожалению, использование функций делает невозможным использование индексов при склейке. И это не лечится. Как вариант конечно можно указать конструкцию `(s.field1=c.field1 or (s.field1 is null and c.field1 is null))` и так для каждого параметра. Но OR оптимизатор то-же очень не любит и сложно сказать, что будет быстрее работать.

Comment: В итоге использовал второй вариант, который с OR. Думал, что есть другие решения, но придется использовать это.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться вместо обычного JOIN или запятой LEFT JOIN, который обяжет, чтобы в результирующем запросе остались все записи из левой таблицы

```
SELECT
  otherfield
FROM
  table1 c
LEFT JOIN
  table2 s
ON
  s.field1 = c.field1 AND
  s.field3 = c.field3 AND
  s.field3 = c.field3
WHERE
  s.phone_number = '$phone_number'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: К сожалению, возвращает результат, только если не NULL в необходимых полях. С NULL та же ситуация(